# Can't access methods of @Injectable inside Expectations() of Jmockit?

Tags: java, junit, jmockit

I define an @Injectable in my test class as below

```
@Injectable
    IndividualPaymentServiceLocal individualPaymentService;
```

and then initialize this reference inside @Before method of Junit as

```
individualPaymentService = new MockUp<IndividualPaymentServiceLocal>() {
            @Mock
            public void $init() {
            }

            @Mock
            public List<IndividualPayment> search(@Nullable String clinicId, @NotNull TimeWindow timeWindow, @Nullable IndividualPaymentFetchConfig fetchConfig) {
                return paymentsList_1;
            }
        }.getMockInstance();
```

> IndividualPaymentServiceLocal is a local EJB interface and has a
>   search() method that I mock as shown above to return an ArrayList
>   paymentsList_1. Now in my one of @Test methods, I wish to return a
>   different ArrayList so I try to use Jmockit's Expectations like below

```
new Expectations(){
            individualPaymentService.search(anyString,any,any); result=paymentsList_2;
        };
```

but search method is not resolved on individualPaymentService reference so code doesn't compile. Outside Expectations, its resolved. Am I missing something? I am using IntelliJ Idea. Please suggest.

Comment: I am thankful to any person who read this question to answer it. I missed one curly braces in - new Expectations(){}; . It needs to be like- new Expectations(){{}};

Comment: Every `@Injectable` field is automatically assigned by JMockit with an automatically created mock instance, so you shouldn't reassign it later. Also, try not to mix these two different APIs (the Expectations API which uses `@Mocked`, `@Injectable`, etc. and the Mockups API) in the same test. I would suggest looking at example tests in the JMockit documentation.

Comment: @Rogério: Thanks for the suggestion, I will look into examples